# useContext returns values multiple times when called only 1 time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-context

I'd like to get the data from my API and store it in a **context** in order to use that data on multiple component. There are multiple endpoints from this API, and I need the user id to reach them. To do that, I get the id from **useParams** and change the id with the hook **setID** passed by the context.

The problem is : when I console.log the data after I change the ID, the console display 4 differents data, one by step in the useEffect :

- First with the **initial state** of context (I understand that one)
- Second with the **ID** changed
- Third with the **error** changed
- And the last one with the **data** changed

But I only set the id in the useEffect callback, so I don't understand why it fires 4 times when value is changed 1 time.

I don't know if I'm doing it in the right way (if using context is a bad thing there), or just I misunderstand useEffect and useContext.

```
// Component receiving the data
function APIChecker(){
    const {id} = useParams();
    const data = useContext(DataContext);
    data.setID(id);
    
    console.log(data);

    return(
        <>
        </>
    );
}

export default APIChecker;
```

```
// Context
export const DataContext = React.createContext();

export const DataProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [id, setID] = useState(null);

    const initialData = {
        globalInfo: [],
        activity: [],
        averageSession: [],
        performance: []
    }

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
    const [error, setError] = useState(404);

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "http://localhost:3000/user/";
        const fetchData = async () =>{
            Promise.all([
                fetch(url + id),
                fetch(url + id + "/activity"),
                fetch(url + id + "/average-sessions"),
                fetch(url + id + "/performance")
            ]).then(([responseGlobal, responseActivity, responseSessions, responsePerformance]) => Promise.all([responseGlobal.json(), responseActivity.json(), responseSessions.json(), responsePerformance.json(), responseGlobal.status
            ])).then(([responseGlobal, responseActivity, responseSessions, responsePerformance, statusError]) => {
                setError(statusError);
                setData({
                    globalInfo: responseGlobal,
                    activity: responseActivity,
                    averageSessions: responseSessions,
                    performance: responsePerformance
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(error);
            });
        }
        if(id != null){
            fetchData();
        }

    }, [id])

    return(
        <DataContext.Provider value={{id, data, setID, error}}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime your child component APIChecker invokes setID, that is going to trigger the useEffect in the parent since in the dependancy array you have passed id.
This in turn is calling the APIs multiple times.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    /*your implementation*/
},[id]);
```

if you want this invoked just once, just pass empty array as dependancy, like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    /*your implementation*/
},[]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now I have 2 returns in my console : first is still the same, and the second is the update of the id hook, but data and error don't change. I want to update the data everytime the id changes

Comment: I understand it now, and it is logging 4 time quite correctly might I add.
Your context is composed of 4 individual elemenets:
 - id (state)
 - function (setID)
 - error (state)
 - data (state)

Bear in mind when we set the state, that causes a rerender.
These setting of the state id, data and error are not happening at the same time, but rather at individual times. So everytime react updates the state via the setter function it passes the updated state to dependant childern.
Try removing at least 2 states from contxt to verify!

Comment: Well I can't get the id inside the data state, because it will render infinitly, but I can put error inside of data. This erased a log but still got 1 log I don't expect to have. If you have an idea to only have 1 state and still have the id in the callback of useEffect ...

Comment: okay so the way I would probably approach is that I would rather have 2 useEffects on the child component. One would have zero args in dependancy array. The other useEffect would have data as an arg in dependancy array. This way the first time child mounts it makes the API call by invoking setID and that would happen once.
The other use effect with data as dependancy would be invoked when data changes.

Comment: Either I don't see how you do this, or it doesn't work like I did 

`useEffect(() => {data.setID(id)});   useEffect(() => {console.log(data)}, [data]);`

Comment: useEffect(() => {         data.setID(id);     },[]);      useEffect(() => {         console.log(data);     }, [data]);
just add an empty dependancy array to the first useEffect. the rest is correct.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work unfortunatly. Still got the middle log

Comment: Have a look and see if this suffices your need:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-fast-vreepi?file=/src/DataProvider.js

Comment: Perfect ! So using a useEffect on DataContext was a mistake. A simple async function works.